# Could not find io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, automation, build.gradle

I'm getting some errors :

```
    Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 
':gisett-backend:classpath'. 
Could not find io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE. Searched in the following locations: - 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
 - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.9.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.9.RELEASE.pom
```

Here the build.gradle :
github.com/EstherSD/gis/blob/main/build.gradle

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to comment/remove line 15, since this artifact is deployed on Maven Central no additional setup needed to find it.

Comment: It does not help

Answer (score 2):

Adding the spring URL in the repositories section fixed it for me:

```
 repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release"
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change from

```
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
```

to

```
    maven {
        url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release"
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023 notes that repo.spring.io will no longer be accessible anonymously, except for /plugins-snapshot and /plugins-milestone.